# Grails 4.0.3 Unit Testing problems when saving an entity in the database

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I first started to unit test my file manager api creating a test method which tries to delete a file from a non existent owner (part), as follows.

```
void "Deleting a file from a non existent part" (){
        when:
        request.method = 'DELETE'
        request.setParameter("partId","1234567891011")
        request.setParameter("fileId","65465654546654654")
        controller.deleteMetafiles()

        then:
        response.status == 404
        response.json.message == "Part not found."
        //println(response.getJson())
    }
```

The code above works as expected.

Now I would like to insert a Metafile in the memory database in order to delete it. But it is not being possible.

```
void "Deleting a valid file from an existent part" (){
        given:
        new Metafile(id: '1111111111', filename: 'test.pdf', title: '',
                description: '', uploadedOn: new Date(),
                partId: '2222222222', uploadedBy: 'Alfred', userId: '333333333').save()

        when:
        setupSpec()
        request.method = 'DELETE'
        request.setParameter("partId","2222222222")
        request.setParameter("fileId","1111111111")
        def model = controller.deleteMetafiles()

        then:
        response.status == 200


        println("response status")
        println(response.status)
        println("response status")
    }
```

Could anyone please explain me where I am doing the mistake? The response is 404 (Part not found). The same response of the first unit test. But in the second test I created  a Metafile in the given section.

Thanks!

Alfredo

Below my entire source code.

```
package br.gov.cmb.cmbarq.tests

import br.gov.cmb.cmbarq.controllers.v1.MetafileController
import br.gov.cmb.cmbarq.domain.Metafile
import grails.testing.web.controllers.ControllerUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification
import grails.testing.gorm.DataTest

class MetafileControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<MetafileController>, DataTest{
    def setupSpec() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "Getting the amount of files from a non existent part"() {
        when:
        request.method = 'GET'
        request.setParameter("partId","1234567891011")
        controller.getMetafilesAmount()

        then:
        response.status == 404

    }

    void "Listing files of an non existent part"() {
        when:
        request.method = 'GET'
        request.setParameter("partId","1234567891011")
        controller.listMetafiles()
        then:
        response.status == 404

    }

    void "Deleting a file from a non existent part" (){
        when:
        request.method = 'DELETE'
        request.setParameter("partId","1234567891011")
        request.setParameter("fileId","65465654546654654")
        controller.deleteMetafiles()

        then:
        response.status == 404
        response.json.message == "Part not found."
        //println(response.getJson())
    }


    void "Deleting a valid file from an existent part" (){
        given:
        List <Metafile> sampleMetafiles = [new Metafile(id: '1111111111', filename: 'test.pdf', title: '',
                description: '', uploadedOn: new Date(),
                partId: '2222222222', uploadedBy: 'Alfred', userId: '333333333'),
                                           new Metafile(id: '1111111112', filename: 'test2.pdf', title: '',
                                                   description: '', uploadedOn: new Date(),
                                                   partId: '2222222221', uploadedBy: 'Alfred', userId: '333333334')
                ]


        when:
        request.method = 'DELETE'
        request.setParameter("partId","2222222222")
        request.setParameter("fileId","1111111111")
        controller.deleteMetafiles()

        then:
        println(model.size())
        model.size() == 1


    }   
}
```

Comment: Does your test implement either `DomainUnitTest` or `DataTest`?

Comment: Invoking `setupSpec` from within a spec method is an usual thing to do.  Can you show a more complete test file that shows just enough of the class to support the 2 test methods you show?

Comment: Is the call to `.save()` returning non-null?

Comment: I will respond you.

Comment: "I will respond you" - Sounds good.

Comment: I edited my first post and showed all the code. The test which is not working is void "Deleting a valid file from an existent part" (). This test is that I have to persist data in the database.

Comment: It is not working, but I have alreay tried a lot of things. My last attempt was to verify if the model had anything which was saved. But there was nothing saved. The response is:  Condition not satisfied:

model.size() == 1
|     |      |
[:]   0      false

 at br.gov.cmb.cmbarq.tests.MetafileControllerSpec.Deleting a valid file from an existent part(MetafileControllerSpec.groovy:70)

Comment: As I said, I complemented my first post with Below my entire source code, and put all the code of the test. The test which is not working is the last one, where I do nedd to persist data and veryfy it later. Thank you!

Comment: It does not look like you are mocking the domain class.  If you override `Class[] getDomainClassesToMock()` and have it return `Metafile`, does that change anything?

Comment: "But in the second test I created a Metafile in the given section." - https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/e3ad4f6fb20debf881aeb6b9cc4653a5 - In your `"Deleting a valid file from an existent part"` test method you are creating a `List` of `Metafile` instances but are not doing anything with that list.  That is not going to result in anything being saved to the database.

Comment: The 2 `"Deleting a valid file from an existent part"` methods you show in the question now have different implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ws didn't have a service. There were only controller and domain because of its simplicity.

I tried to create a service e and decoupled service from controller.

In my unit test, I instantiated the service as a Stub and it worked as expected.

I will continue doing this and post here any questions if I have further problems.

Thanks.